# Excel: Formula for adding row elements based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two rows of data in excel:

Person1's data:

```
country1 country2 country3 country4 score1 Personcurrenttotal
France Spain France Croatia 0-1 9
```

Winning data:

```
winningteam1 winningteam2 winningteam3 winningteam4 winningscore1
France France France Spain  0-1
```

and a row of scores underneath the winning teams, that's how much would be added to the PersoncurrentTotal if country1/2/3 etc matched winningteam1/2/3 etc.

```
2 7 3 8 2
```

9 is the person's current score for the week. For each item in a person's row values, if the cell in the person's row matched the winning value, I want to add the score of that row to the person's overall score.

In this case, the 0th, 2nd and 4th rows are the same, so to 9; 2,3 and 2 are added, so then the 9 should update to 9 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 16.

Could someone explain the formula for me to do this in excel. I can find stuff about nested IF statements which I don't want (the row cells are independent) and I can see how to do for one cell using SUMIF, but I can't see how to just take in the rows as a whole and do the calculation that way instead of having to do it on a per-cell level?

(this excercise can only be done in excel, I could do this easily in python).

Comment: I should mention that in reality, the two rows are about 500 cells long, hence why i'm looking for a neater solution on a per-row level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The 9 and the 16 will have to be in different cells as 'PersonOldTotal' and 'PersonNewTotal' as far as I can see. I just put them below the table:

[image: See this picture here]

Formula should be:

```
=SUM(IF(Person1'sDataRow=WinningDataRow,RowOfScores))+PersonOldTotal
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The IF works like this:
It will return an array of 2,0,3,0,2: The ones that match will be their respective values in the scores row, otherwise the score will be 0.
The sum then sums this up. 
You could also include the previous score (9) in this sum, however I kept it separate and added it at the end to make it more transparent for you.